# a limit property at infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $k\in(0,1)$ is fixed and $L$ is a finite value. Is it possible to say if

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(kx)=L.$

Comment: As long as $k>0$ you're good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0, \exists N_0 > 1 \text{ such that if } x > N_0 \Rightarrow |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon$. Now choose $N_1 = \dfrac{N_0}{k} > 1 \Rightarrow \text{ if } x > N_1 \Rightarrow kx > k\left(\dfrac{N_0}{k}\right) = N_0 \Rightarrow |f(kx)-L| < \varepsilon$

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Consider the change of variable, $y=kx$. As $x \rightarrow \infty$, $y \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 2):

By definition we have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ means

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\; \exists A>0,\; x>A\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
so for the selected $\epsilon>0$, and for $B=kA$ we have $(kx>B\iff x>\frac Bk)\implies |f(kx)-L|<\epsilon$ hence we get $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(kx)=L$$